# SWT how to access efficiently other controls from SelectionListener

Tags: java, swt, listener, jface

I have a swt button on `ViewPart` with attached `MySelectionListener implements SelectionListener`
There is also another button which is disabled.

Listener should do its work, if the return result of the work is `true`, it should enable the other button.

My question what would be the best way to do that?

For now what I do is to pass the button as constructor argument to 'MySelectionListener', I guess there is some other way to do it.

Another option is to to create an interface

```
public interface EnableButton(){
  void enableButton();
}
```

And have the `View` implement it, then pass the interface to 'MySelectionListener' as constructor parameter once again...
I also don't like this approach, because this will require to create and implement multiple interfaces for each update or any other task that I would need.

*I am not using any injection frameworks*

Answer (score 0):

Since your selectionListener seems to be only relevant for your ViewPart, you can implement it as an inner class inside your ViewPart.

Or you pass your ViewPart as constructor argument to MySelectionListener. Then let the method MySelectionListener.widgetSelected delegate to a method of ViewPart, where you have access to all the stuff you need, for example the button.